# BeautifulSoup's find_all method going in loop

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I'm doing some scraping exercises with BeautifulSoup, but I've generated an event that seem going in loop.

This is my code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

# Print all links in the page

linkpage = "https://automatetheboringstuff.com/chapter12/"
page = requests.get(linkpage)
page.econding = "utf-8"
data = page.text
html = BeautifulSoup(data, "html5lib")

for link in html.find_all("a"):
    print(link)
```

When I execute this script CPU goes to max, nothing is printed and execution going in loop. Why?

Two important consideration:

- This happens only under Linux (both with Python 2 and 3).
  I do not get the same behavior under Windows: there works good and all links is printed correctly! :‑|
- This happens only with URL indicated in the variable *linkpage*. When I change it with others (i.e. https://stackoverflow.com/) it works properly.

**Edit:**

Changing parser to xlml it works.

Why with html5lib I've this problem (for now only on this specific page)?

Comment: Works fine by me (linux/python3), Tried also `lxml` parser and it's ok. Are you sure this is the URL that's giving you problems?

Comment: Try findAll() instead of find_all() and check

Comment: @AndrejKesely, with lxml parser it works! All others URLs I've tested haven't this problem. Only with this URL the execution didn't give errors but remains in loop.

Comment: @SmashGuy, I've tested findAll() but it has the same behavior of find_all().

Comment: Our of interest is there a reason why you're changing the page encoding? This might be interfering with the html5 parser.

Comment: @Eugenio, in your code it works fine for 'lxml' but for 'html5lib' it uses maximum resources  because while using html5lib it constructs the full html of the page. I think that is the major reason for this,  for more information on html parsing libraries you can check this [docs] https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#installing-a-parser

Comment: @Hevlastka I've changed encoding to avoid errors about failed unicode char decoding. I can skip the econding line, the problem remain.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
    from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
    import requests

    # Print all links in the page

    linkpage = "https://automatetheboringstuff.com/chapter12/"
    page = requests.get(linkpage)
    page.econding = "utf-8"
    data = page.text
    html = BeautifulSoup(data)

    all_link=html.find_all('a')
    for link in all_link:
        print(link.get('href'))
```

Comment: It works because it uses _xlml_ as default parser. If I set
`html = BeautifulSoup(data, "html5lib")` I have the same "in loop" execution.